# Add Google Translate API in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, api, maven, translate

I want to make a simple program using google translate API. I have an account and key already,but I am having trouble with the imports.

```
import com.google.api.GoogleAPI;    
import com.google.api.translate.Language;  
import com.google.api.translate.Translate;
```

They cannot be resolved. I am trying to follow these instructions:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#google-api-client
but after extracting the  google-api-java-client-1.17.0-rc.zip file and trying to add only the jar files I need, I cannot find the following:
jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar
protobuf-java-2.2.0.jar
xpp3-1.1.4c.jar

I have tried adding the entire google-api-services-translate-v2-rev27-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar file with maven and manually without maven. It shows up under referenced libraries and in the build configuration, but still does not achieve anything. I do not know if I am missing something important. I want to use it in a simple application, not having to do with android or google app engine. Please help! Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to download this: http://google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/files/google-api-java-client-1.17.0-rc.zip
It contains the required libraries.